# Generator of a finite dimensional separable commutative algebra over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional separable commutattive algebra over a field $k$.
The book *A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory* by Cohen says that $A$ has a single generator as an algebra over $k$. I tried to prove this but failed.
$A$ is a finite product of separable extension fields $K_i$ over $k$.
It is well known that each $K_i$ has a single generator over $k$, but I don't know how to use this fact to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be false when $k$ has characteristic $p$.  For example, $\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_4$ cannot be generated by a single element over $\mathbb{F}_2$, because we would have $\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_4\cong \mathbb{F}_2 [X]/p$ for some polynomial $p$.  This can only happen if $p$ is the product of two distinct degree $2$ irreducibles, but there is only one degree $2$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

On the other hand, if $k$ has characteristic $0$, we can get around this problem.  If $A$ is a finite product $\prod_i K_i$, we can write $K_i \cong k[X]/p_i$ for irreducible polynomials $p_i$.  If the $p_i$ are distinct, then $A \cong k[X]/\prod_i p_i$, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  If not, we can replace $p_i(X)$ by $p_i(X+n)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  In characteristic $0$, these are all distinct polynomials, so we can ensure that $\prod_i p_i$ has no repeated factors.

---

Here is a proof in the more general case when $k$ is infinite: as above, we are done if we can show that there are infinitely many distinct polynomials among $\{p_i(X+a) \mid a\in k\}$.  Suppose that there are only finitely many.  By the pigeonhole principle, there must be an infinite set $S\subset k$ such that $p_i(X+a) = p_i(X+b)$ for all $a,b\in S$.

But then $p_i(a)=p_i(b)$ for all $a,b\in S$, so $p_i$ is constant, as a function, on an infinite subset of $k$, which can only happen if $p_i$ itself is constant.

Comment: *This can only happen if $p$ is the product of two distinct degree $2$ irreducibles,*  Would you elaborate on this?

Comment: @WilliamCurtis If $p=\prod_i p_i^{a_i}$ is the factorization into irreducibles, then $k[X]/p \cong \prod_i k[X]/p_i^{a_i}$ by CRT.  This is a product of fields iff there are no nilpotents iff $a_i = 1$ for all $i$.  In this case, $k[X]/p_i$ is an extension of $k$ with degree $\deg{p_i}$.

Comment: CRT only proves the existence of a decomposition. It doesn't prove that the decomposition is unique.

Comment: @WilliamCurtis I don't see how uniqueness is significant for my argument; a product of fields is uniquely a product of fields.

Comment: *"$\mathbb{F}_4\times \mathbb{F}_4\cong \mathbb{F}_2 [X]/p$ for some polynomial $p$.  This can only happen if $p$ is the product of two distinct degree 2 irreducibles"* If the decomposition is not unique, this might happen even if $p$ is a square of an irreducible polynomial. No?

Comment: @WilliamCurtis If $p$ is the square of an irreducible, then $k[X]/p$ has nilpotents, and cannot be a product of fields.

Comment: @WilliamCurtis By the way, when $R$ is a principal ideal domain, we do have uniqueness of these kinds of decompositions of $R$-modules, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).